# Ordering for Pattern matching in Subscripts

Tags: pattern-matching, replacement

I have some transformation rules acting on subscripted variables. When I match the  a product the order matters.

```
Subscript[Z, 2, 1] Subscript[Z, 3, 1] /. 
 Subscript[Z, l_, m_] Subscript[Z, k_, n_] -> {{l, m}, {k, n}}
Subscript[Z, 3, 1] Subscript[Z, 2, 1] /. 
 Subscript[Z, l_, m_] Subscript[Z, k_, n_] -> {{l, m}, {k, n}}
```

both cases yield

```
{{3, 1}, {2, 1}}.
```

It seems k,n always get assigned the subscripts with the smaller first value. Why is this and how can I influence this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's happening only indirectly involves the pattern matching. Mathematica, when dealing with operations that are [`Orderless`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Orderless.html), will put the arguments into a canonical ordering (described [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/StructuralOperations.html)). In this case, an expression like

```
Subscript[Z, 2, 1] Subscript[Z, 3, 1]
```

can be seen to be equivalent to

```
Times[Subscript[Z,2,1], Subscript[Z,3,1]]
```

using `FullForm`. Now, because multiplication is commutative, `Times` has the `Orderless` attribute, so mathematica will always put the terms into that canonical order, and the canonical order puts `Subscript[Z,2,1]` first (it's pretty much a lexicographic ordering). Thus, the order is switched before any patterns are matched by `ReplaceAll` (which is the name of the `/.` operation).

**EDIT** to add: There aren't necessarily a lot of easy ways to avoid this, but I can think of two. One is if you really are interested in conventional multiplication, but want to retain the ordering of terms anyway. The most expedient way to keep `Times` from wreaking havoc with its `Orderless`ness is to get rid of the attribute. Now, you could do this by using `Unprotect` on `Times` and changing its attributes, but this will probably make a mess. A better approach, and one that it is less likely to turn your Mathematica session into a smoking ruin, is to use [`Block`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Block.html) to **temporarily** change `Times`:

```
Block[{Times},
 Subscript[Z, 3, 1] Subscript[Z, 2, 1] /.
  Subscript[Z, l_, m_] Subscript[Z, k_, n_] :> {{l, m}, {k, n}}]
```

> ```
> {{3, 1}, {2, 1}}
> ```

This is one of the rare use cases where you actually want to use `Block` instead of `Module`. The other possibility is that you are referring to some operation that looks like multiplication but isn't commutative. In that case, [`NonCommutativeMultiply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NonCommutativeMultiply.html) (written with the `**` infix operator) has you covered:

```
 Subscript[Z, 3, 1] ** Subscript[Z, 2, 1] /.
  Subscript[Z, l_, m_] ** Subscript[Z, k_, n_] :> {{l, m}, {k, n}}
```

> ```
> {{3, 1}, {2, 1}}
> ```